# Passing data from Java process to a python script

Tags: java, python, process

I call a external Python script as Java process and want to send data to this. I create a process and try to send a string. Later the python script should wait for a new input from Java, work with this data and wait again(while true loop).

**Python Code (test.py):**

```
input = input("")
print("Data: " + input)
```

**Java Code:**

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("py ./scripts/test.py");

BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new
        OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
        InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

System.out.println("Output:");
String s = null;
out.write("testdata");
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

The process and output of simple prints works, but not with `input` and `BufferedWriter`.
Is it possible to send data to this python input with a Java process?

I read from other solutions:

- create a Python listener and send messages to this script
- import the external script to Jython and pass data

Are this better solutions to handle my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Process class in java

**what is process class ?**
this class is used to start a .exe or any script using java

**How it can help you**
Create your python script to accept command line variables and send your data from java class to python script.

for Example:

```
        System.out.println("Creating Process"); 

        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("my.py"); 
        Process pro = builder.start(); 

        // wait 10 seconds 
        System.out.println("Waiting"); 
        Thread.sleep(10000); 

        // kill the process 
        pro.destroy(); 
        System.out.println("Process destroyed");
```

Answer (score 0):

> Later the python script should wait for a new input from Java

If this has to happen while the python process is still a subprocess of the Java process, then you will have to use redirection of I/O using `ProcessBuilder.redirect*( Redirect.INHERIT )` or `ProcessBuilder.inheritIO()`. Like this:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder().command( "python.exe", "./scripts/test.py" )
        .inheritIO().start();
```

If the python process is going to be separate (which is not the case here, I think) then you will have to use some mechanism to communicate between them like client/server or shared file, etc.